# Wired network cannot resolve hostnames(can ping by ip), however wireless works fine

Tags: networking, dns, wired

The problem is pretty much in the title, I am on Ubuntu 17.10, any ideas on what the cause could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved it, wasn't an Ubuntu, but rather a router setup issue.

I tried to request a static IP in the router, which was already reserved, so it caused all kinds of problems.

If someone struggles with it, make sure you either set a fixed IP in the router by MAC address, and let DHCP handle everything normally, or set the desired IP in Ubuntu(or any other client), but not both.